# Format array of objects with different keys into table data

Tags: javascript, object, html-table, format, lodash

I'm trying to determine the simplest way to map an array of objects into data that can be used to render a table. For example:

**Data:**

```
const data = [{
  name: "foo",
  phone: "123456",
  email: "foo@bar.com"
},
{
  name: "bar",
  address: "123 Main",
  country: "USA"
}];
```

Table:

```
+------+--------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| name | phone  |    email    |  address |  country  |
+------+--------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| foo  | 123456 | foo@bar.com |          |           |
| bar  |        |             | 123 Main |    USA    |
+------+--------+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

As you can see, the objects share the name key but otherwise are completely different. All the keys and values are dynamic in this data so they could be anything.

The best way I've found to get all the unique keys from all the objects so `name, phone, email, address, country` and then loop through each object again padding the entry with the attributes that it doesn't have. Like this:

```
const formatData = (data) => {
  let keys = new Set([]);
  for (const entry of data) {
    keys = new Set([...keys, ...Object.keys(entry)])
  }
  const columns = Array.from(keys);
  const rows = [];

  for (const entry of data) {
    const row = [];
    for (const col of columns) {
      row.push(entry[col])
    }
    rows.push(row);
  }
  return {
    columns,
    rows
  }
}
```

This will return data formatted like this:

```
{
  columns: ["name", "phone", "email", "address", "country"],
  rows: [["foo", "123456", "foo@bar.com", undefined, undefined], ["bar", undefined, undefined, "123 Main", "USA"]]
}
```

From there when I'm rendering my table I can just loop through the columns and render a  for each, and then loop the the rows and each item is a  and each nested array is a .

This works fine, but I feel like my algorithm is not efficient or readable. Is there a better way to get data into this format. I'm also using lodash so lodash functions would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the code more readable (I hope :)) by using `Array.flatMap()` to create the columns, and lodash's `_.at()` with `Array.map()` to get the rows' data:

```js
const formatData = data => {
  const columns = Array.from(new Set(data.flatMap(Object.keys)));
  
  const rows = data.map(row => _.at(row, columns));

  return {
    columns,
    rows
  }
}

const data = [{"name":"foo","phone":"123456","email":"foo@bar.com"},{"name":"bar","address":"123 Main","country":"USA"}];

const result = formatData(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Another option to get columns is to merge all objects, and then get the keys:

```js
const formatData = data => {
  const columns = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));
  
  const rows = data.map(row => _.at(row, columns));

  return {
    columns,
    rows
  }
}

const data = [{"name":"foo","phone":"123456","email":"foo@bar.com"},{"name":"bar","address":"123 Main","country":"USA"}];

const result = formatData(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```